# Random Forest Classification Model in R-Programming

Tags: r, model, classification, random-forest

I am trying to code in R programming, this scenario:

- Obtain the confusion matrix for the testing set and report the accuracy, precision, and recall.

```r
set.seed(6522048)
library(randomForest)
model_rf2 <- randomForest(target ~ age+sex+cp+trestbps+chol+restecg+exang+ca, data=train.data, ntree = 5)

print("======================================================================================================================")
print('Confusion Matrix: TESTING set based on random forest model built using 5 trees')
test.data.predict <- predict(model_rf2, test.data, type = "class")

# Construct the confusion matrix
conf.matrix <- table(test.data$target, test.data.predict)[,c('0','1')]
rownames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Actual", rownames(conf.matrix), sep = ": target=")
colnames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Prediction", colnames(conf.matrix), sep = ": target=")

# Print nicely formatted confusion matrix
format(conf.matrix,justify="centre",digit=2)
```

And I keep getting this error:

```r
Error in `[.default`(table(test.data$target, test.data.predict), , c("0", : subscript out of bounds
Traceback:

1. table(test.data$target, test.data.predict)[, c("0", "1")]
2. `[.table`(table(test.data$target, test.data.predict), , c("0", 
 .     "1"))
3. NextMethod()
```

Any help on how to get rid of the error and get the testing graph for what I need be awesome.